# Singleton with JBoss SEAM

Tags: synchronization, seam

I have the following code:

```
@Name("myService")
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
@Stateless
public class MyService {
  private Service service;

  private Service getService() {
    if (service == null) {
      service = Service.create(url, new QName("URL",
        "Envelope"));
    }

    return service;
  }    

  public synchronized Port getPort() {
    return getService().getPort();
  }
}
```

And getPort method is invoked from different threads. "Service.create" takes a lot of time and I've found that actually it is invoked more than once. So it looks like more than one instance of  MyService class is created and that's why **synchronized** doesn't help.

I've changed annotations to:

```
@AutoCreate
@Startup
@Name("myService")
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
```

And now it seems to work fine: only one instance is created and access to the getPort() method is synchronized.

Could anyone explain why the first case doesn't wok as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A @Stateless bound to an Application scope is an oxymoron

you are asking Java EE to provide a component that has no state, to live in the Application Scope, shared by all users

When you removed the @Stateless annotation, seam handled the instance of the component and placed it in the Application Scope, it also created it at startup, hence having a singleton